# Android: Read Gamepad Input Events from Service

Tags: android

How do I read Gamepad Input Events from the background when my view is not longer visible? It's fine if the solution requires root. I am currently targeting USB Gamepads, but a solution that works with BT Gamepads as well is a plus.

I know there are Android apps that read Gamepad events and translate them to screen touch events from the background, however I am looking to invoke some custom actions in the background when certain buttons are pressed.